# Cross-thread exception after async call

Tags: c#, database, multithreading, async-await, synchronizationcontext

The code block below causes cross-thread invalid operation exception only with Npgsql (not sqlclient, sqlite, mysql, file read async).

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var strBuilder = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder()
   {
        Host = "localhost",
        Username = "postgres",
        Password = "password"
   };
   using (var conn = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(strBuilder.ConnectionString))
   {
      try
      {
          await conn.OpenAsync();
          if (conn.State ==ConnectionState.Open)
          {
             MessageBox.Show("Connected");
             this.button1.Text = "CROSS-THREAD-With-NPGSQL";
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I looked at the code from Npgsql and found this link: 
https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/2dd46e7c544caf3302ca7b89dd888a16dccf5c2c/src/Npgsql/PGUtil.cs

At the bottom of the file, it said:

> This mechanism is used to temporarily set the current synchronization
>   context to null while executing Npgsql code, making all await
>   continuations execute on the thread pool. This replaces the need to
>   place ConfigureAwait(false) everywhere, and should be used in all
>   surface async methods, without exception.

I have got quite an explanation from Roji (owner of the Npgsql repos) but I need to understand why I don't see similar issue with other drivers. Is the way npgsql temporary disabling the SynchronizationContext considered best practice? I am trying to look at the source code from other drivers but it will take a while so I hope I can get some help to head in the right direction.

Edit 1: 
Stephen Cleary gave a very detailed answer below but I want to post some of my findings here as well. It may help others. 
On 09/24/16, npgsql replaced all ConfigureAwait(false) by NoSynchronizationContextScope. As Stephen explained, the NoSynchronizationContextScope temporary cleared the caller context, thus causing such behavior. ConfigureAwait(false), on the other hand, doesn't do such thing and that should not have been replaced. To verify, I installed npgsql 3.1.7 (the version right before 09/24/16) and I didn't see the cross-thread exception anymore.

Comment: Imo they should have left the decision up to you to configure the continuation using `ConfigureAwait`. Now by setting the context to null they created a difficult to spot side-effect.

Comment: @PeterBons It also forces you to write better code, separating out the UI code from the business logic, rather than mingling them, as the OP is doing here.

Comment: Explicitly set continuation on GUI thread: `conn.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(true);`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov That wouldn't change anything.  As the quote says, they're removing the synchronization context.  You'd need to capture it yourself before it removes it, [which would happen on its own if you designed your program well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44418761/cross-thread-exception-after-async-call#comment75836504_44418761), or you could re-set it after they remvoe it, if you're a masocist and just want to have a mess of code.

Comment: @Servy - ok, I get it.

Comment: @Servy I am mixing the DAL and the UI code so that people can see my point easily. My question is about whether doing what npgsql is doing is considered best practice because I don't see that effect in other drivers. Take sqlclient as an example, it  achieves async IO and then still bring the code back to where it was before calling await.

Comment: @HNGO If you *didn't* mix the UI and non-UI code *then the program would work perfectly*.  The problem only exists when you mix the two.  As for your question, that's asking for opinions, and is not an appropriate question on SO as a result.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. Npgsql supresses the synchronization context for internal calls, I doubt they ever planned that it would impact the caller as well. This is actually an interesting and tricky side-effect, I realize that some code I wrote have the same bug. Adding a `await Task.Yield()` at the beginning of the `OpenAsync()` method would fix it, I wonder if there is a smarter way

Comment: @KevinGosse As Roji (npgsql repos owner) explained to me that is what npgsql intended to do, I would not call it a bug. It is not like npgsql doing something wrong, I am just thinking the way that other drivers handling IO async is more elegant.

Comment: @HNGO I've found your discussion on GitHub, and quoting Roji: `Your own function, awaiting on OpenAsync(), should have its SynchronizationContext properly set, and that is what will make your code resume back in the UI thread after Npgsql completes its own part.`. I stand my point: this is done for internal reasons, he doesn't expect the caller to be impacted. Your own function has the synchronization context properly set, but because it is overwritten in a hard-to-predict side-effect, the code doesn't resume back to the UI thread

Comment: @KevinGosse I got your point. Btw, I think adding Task.Yield() would affect the library performance.

Comment: @HNGO Definitely, though probably negligible compared to establishing a connection to a database. But that's why I'm trying to think of a smarter way

Comment: @HNGO In the end, Npgsql could fix the issue simply by replacing `await Open(true, cancellationToken);` by `return Open(true, cancellationToken)` in `OpenAsync`

Comment: @KevinGosse Your solution may fix OpenAsync(). Still there are other surface API having the same issue. I think npgsql needs a more systematic approach overall. Anyway, Roji confirmed this is a bug. You were right from the beginning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is the way npgsql temporary disabling the SynchronizationContext considered best practice?

No. The *idea* is not a bad one: to `null` out `SynchronizationContext.Current` for internal methods. However, [their implementation](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/2dd46e7c544caf3302ca7b89dd888a16dccf5c2c/src/Npgsql/PGUtil.cs#L179) is buggy because it does clear the caller's `SynchronizationContext.Current`.

This is because the original `SynchronizationContext` must be restored *synchronously*, not after an `await`. `NoSynchronizationContextScope.Disposable` must be disposed *before* the surface async method returns an incomplete task to its caller.

Thus, using [this simple example](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/2a66d94c9b64115917ef052f828c83f8420a2834/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlLargeObjectManager.cs#L134):

```
public async Task<NpgsqlLargeObjectStream> OpenReadAsync(uint oid, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  using (NoSynchronizationContextScope.Enter())
    return await OpenRead(oid, true);
}
```

The order of operations is:

- Some thread calls `OpenReadAsync`.
- The `cancellationToken` is checked.
- `NoSynchronizationContextScope.Enter` saves and then clears `SynchronizationContext.Current`.
- `OpenRead` is called and returns an incomplete task.
- The task is `await`ed, which causes `OpenReadAsync` to return to its caller.
- **The calling thread has lost its `SynchronizationContext`.**

Later, when the task returned from `OpenRead` completes:

- A thread pool thread is picked up to resume executing `OpenReadAsync`.
- The `NoSynchronizationContextScope.Disposable` is disposed, which sets `SynchronizationContext.Current` to its original value.
- The task returned from `OpenReadAsync` is completed.
- **A thread pool thread now has an incorrect `SynchronizationContext`.**

So, no, I would say that is totally buggy.

This is why [my `SynchronizationContextSwitcher.NoContext`](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/SynchronizationContextSwitcher.cs#L50) forces you to pass in a delegate: so it can force the disposal to occur synchronously. Its usage is more awkward, but it's forced to have correct semantics:

```
public Task<NpgsqlLargeObjectStream> OpenReadAsync(uint oid, CancellationToken cancellationToken) =>
  SynchronizationContextSwitcher.NoContext(async () =>
  {
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    return await OpenRead(oid, true);
  });
```

Comment: well explanation as usual.  I was actually waiting an answer from you when writing this question :) I read your whole blog on async/await a while ago and read 2 other articles of yours today on the very same topic. Thank you!

Comment: @stephen-cleary thanks for the explanation, I'll fix this issue for the next version of Npgsql.

Comment: @stephen-cleary I'm a little confused, from some simple tests when you leave a method that results in a compiler generated class, on exiting the method synchronously it retains its previous context, see the discussion at the end of this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/645#issuecomment-306911483
Are you able to clarify why that is? I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: @Stuart: The key in that conversation is "return a pending `Task`". If the task returned is not yet completed, then the `await` in the calling method will capture its own context and resume on that context. OTOH, if the task returned is already completed, then the calling method will lose its context.

Comment: Ah, I'm with you, so if the whole thing is ran synchronously, by awaiting all completed tasks, using Task.FromResult(...), returning a cached completed task, or whatever, then the calling codes context can be changed inadvertently.

Comment: @Stuart:​​​​ Yes.​​​​

Comment: Odd, just tried that in an example and that doesn't appear to be the case

Comment: That is, provided the method is `async` then it doesn't appear you can change the callers context

Comment: I said you set it from a method marked with `async`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/k5GTsG

Comment: @Stuart: I thought you meant if the *caller* method was `async`. It is interesting that the SyncCtx is copied for async methods - it probably is a side effect of the copy-on-write scope of the logical call context (which is activated by the `async` keyword).

Comment: Yep, that was my limited understanding too, surprised me first time I saw it. I don't think what you've outlined in this example is actually what would happen, I think the technique of synchronously nulling the context would work provided you use it from within an async method. Still a little confused here over this question.

Comment: @Stuart: Good point. It is possible that different runtimes have slightly different semantics here. The copy-on-write call context was added in 4.5, but the SyncCtx-as-part-of-CallContext was always hacky and may have been changed in the last couple years (e.g., 4.6.1 or Core).